# Why is my warforged Forge Domain cleric starting with too much HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, hit-points, warforged, dnd-beyond

[I created a Warforged Cleric of the Forge Domain using the official D&D Beyond tool.](https://ddb.ac/characters/31270418/bpyQtf) It came out with 15 HP at level 1. Where did the extra 4 HP come from? I have a Constitution score of 17 (a +3 modifier), so it should be 8+3=11, right?

I also re-made the character using the Fight Club iOS app, and that app shows the character as having 11 HP.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you go to Edit Character < Class < Manage HP (icon in the top right) what do you see? Are there any values in "HP modifier" or "override HP"? Also do you have any idea why it says you are a "none warforged" cleric?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose that "none" comes from the "gender" box under description. Likely OP put "none" under the assumption that Warforged being what they are don't have genders (or theirs specifically doesn't)

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but you could lower Strength and Constitution by 1 each without affecting anything of consequence, and have 4 more points to bump up your low scores. Unless you *want* your character to have those low scores, which is one way to play. But "wasted" odd-numbered ability scores are a pet peeve of mine. (Not your fault; ability scores are vestigial, and their continued existence is poor game design considering modifiers are all that really matter.)

Comment: Yeah so the “none” is the gender. Warforged don’t have those so... yeah.
Under “manage HP” it shows “Rolled HP” = 12, as if I had d12 for hit points. WEIRD, right? And it still says “d8” below that for hit dice.
The odd numbers in the abilities are because I planned to spend one point in each at level 4 to improve both of them. If I do what you suggest, that will mean at level 4 I’ll only get one ability to go up a point. It would be nice, though, to not have a -1 on DEX... hmmm

Comment: @GMRod: Tangential to the question again, but warforged can sometimes have a gender: "The typical warforged has a sexless body shape. Some warforged ignore the concept of gender entirely, while others adopt a gender identity."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I set up a character like yours after reviewing your character sheet. The only thing that I think it could be is a number entered on the "Manage Hit Points" screen, which you reach by clicking "Manage HP" from the class tab under "edit character":

[image]

[image]

I’ve found another possibility. When set to manual hp, there’s nothin stopping you from putting higher numbers than are possible into rolled hp:

[image]

Comment: But wouldn't the OP have to know they did that?  It doesn't seem like the sort of thing one could do on accident...

Comment: It could be that OP though they had to manually enter the bonus from Constitution and hit 4 here. It's the only way I could recreate that issue.

Comment: Hmm. On your screenshot, you went with Fixed HP. I chose rolled, and mine shows a rolled 12 as if I was rolling d12... Which is really strange, right? Maybe I found a bug?

Comment: I’ve figured it out, methinks.

Comment: I'd suggest cropping those screenshots to remove the irrelevant parts of the images, as they take up a lot of space in your answer.

Comment: I'll work on that.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently the cause of the HP error was that somehow a 12 made its way into the “rolled HP” box in the “Manage Hit Points” popup. I definitely didn’t put it there, so it must have been some sort of bug during character creation.

But it’s now fixed! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to accept your answer (or Thomas's, which guesses at a similar cause) now that you can :)